# React-Router Redirect not working at all, using React-Redux-Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, electron

I am trying to conditionally redirect to other pages within a modal using  from react-router.

I have implemented withRouter at the bottom of the relevant components as well as in the connect function. I am currently not using the Reducer because I have a switch in a root modal component which catches a type and then renders a component. Below is a snippet from the switch.

```
case type.componentName
  return <Redirect to='/component' />
break;
```

However, the new component is still not rendering. It is as if Redirect is not being registered at all. My route is below.

```
  <App>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route component={upperComponent}>
        <Route path="/modal" component={rootComponent}>
          <Route path="/component" component={component} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </App>
```

I was originally rendering pages by modifying the state through a boolean and based upon it, a different component would be rendered. This worked just fine but I would rather have some history from using React-Router when I render new pages. Is there something fundamentally wrong about how I am trying to call Redirect or should I use an entirely different strategy all together?

The code below was requested in a comment. This is in my container component and I have one per component.

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import rootComponent from '../components/rooComponent';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as rootComponentlActions from '../actions/rootComponent';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(rootComponentActions, dispatch);
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(rootComponent));
```

I have also tried adding `export default withRouter(component);` as well in my child component to the root as well as in the root to test it out based upon some examples that I have read in the past. As far as I can tell, it made not difference, good or bad.

Comment: Can you show the part of your code where you are using react-router withRouter() and redux connect()?

Comment: If you check the original post, I have just included the requested code.

Comment: Could it be that `/component` is inside `/modal`, but `<Redirect path='/component' />` is described as absolute path ?

Comment: No change, it logs the type that is sent over and will log anything I put in the switch but the Redirect doesn't go anywhere. I tried logged the Redirect object and it will show that it is going 'to='/modal/component'  in the props Object. However, the key, ref and type function Redirect() key are all null. I don't know what they are for but maybe that's the issue?